# "Transgridem" ou "Transgredem"?

Tags: tempo-verbal

O certo é "portanto, as pessoas não transgridem" ou "portanto, as pessoas não transgredem"?

O Word insiste em dizer que "transgridem" está errado.

Comment: Jonhz, o teu word é que está  transgredir. É *transgridem*. Podes ver a conjugação de qualquer verbo online, por exemplo no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/transgredir).

Comment: Tenha em mente que o corretor ortográfico do Word não é infalível, muitas vezes ele diz que está errada uma palavra que está completamente correta.

Comment: Experimentei, e o Word Online está a aceitar somente *transgridem* no português do Portugal, e *transgredem* no português do Brasil.

Answer (score 4):

A forma correcta para conjugar o verbo transgredir na terceira pessoa do plural, no presente do indicativo, é **"transgridem"**.

Como mostra o [dicionário de verbos online da Porto Editora](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/transgredir):

```
eu                  transgrido
tu                  transgrides
ele, ela, você      transgride
nós                 transgredimos
vós                 transgredis
eles, elas, vocês   transgridem
```